# Regular Expressions: How is group matching useful?

Tags: regex

I've decided to learn some regular expression basics. I am using the Regex One lessons online and I was stuck at [lession 11](http://regexone.com/lesson/11) for a while, but I think I got it now.

This was the task.

"Write a regular expression that matches only the filenames (not including extension) of the PDF files below."

```
task            text                     capture
capture text    file_a_record_file.pdf   file_a_record_file
capture text    file_yesterday.pdf       file_yesterday
skip text       testfile_fake.pdf.tmp
```

There is an input field where you type in the pattern to complete the task. After some trials and errors this is what I came up with.

```
^(file_a_record_file)\.pdf$
```

This will match the file name **file_a_record_file.pdf** but only "capture" the **file_a_record_file**. What's the difference?... between matching and "capturing"? And how is this useful? How is this "group matching"?

Now this does work for the first file, but not for the second file. The task says I need to make a pattern that will match and capture the file name of both files, excluding the extension. So this is what I came up next.

```
^(file_.*)\.pdf$
```

Since both file names start with **file_** I thought it would be a good idea to match against that, and then tell it to match any character that follows, and then exit the group with parenthesis (the "group" is what's inside the parenthesis, right?) and escape the dot with a back slash and end with the file name extension.

Can this be described in a more tighter way? The correct solutions are not given on the website. So I have nothing to check my answers against. It's a pity because I think this is a good introduction to regular expressions. The examples given for each lesson are sometimes hard to understand.

And again, how is this useful? He mentions something about command line, I think he means that it can be used to re-use commands or something... well I don't really get it what he's saying.

> Imagine that we have a command line tool that copies each file in a
>   directory up to a server only if it doesn't exist there already, and
>   prints each filename as a result. Now if I want to do another task on
>   each of those filenames, then I will not only need a regular
>   expression that will match the filename, but also some way to extract
>   that information.

Extracting information? What is he talking about? Can someone please tell me how this is useful and give me real world example?

Answer (score 8):

In the lesson you linked to, you are asked to write a regex that captures the file name of these two

```
file_a_record_file.pdf
file_yesterday.pdf
```

and skips

```
testfile_fake.pdf.tmp
```

The simplest regex to do that is

```
(.*)\.pdf$
```

This means match everything that ends in `.pdf` but capture only the file name.

So, why is capturing useful? That depends on the program you are using these regexes with. Capturing patterns allows you to save what you have captured as a variable. For example, using Perl, the first captured pattern is `$1`, the second `$2` etc:

```
echo "Hello world" | perl -ne '/(.+) (.+)/; print "$2 $1\n"'
```

This will print "world Hello" because the first parenthesis **captured** `Hello` and the second captured `world` but we are then printing `$2 $1` so the two matches are inverted.

Other regex implementations allow you to refer to the captured patterns using `\1`, `\2` etc. For example, GNU `sed`:

```
echo "Hello world" | sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/'
```

So, in general, capturing patterns is useful when you need to refer to these patterns later on. This is known as [referencing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and is briefly explained a little later in the tutorials you are doing.

Comment: So this is useful in computer programming? Could you also use this to copy only parts of file name(s) to clipboard? Maybe in some text editor or command line prompt? If capturing means copying to a variable, you should be able to output it to a text file or copy to clipboard? Am I right?...

Comment: @Sammy yes, you are correct. You can also use the captured reference in another regex later, or really any type of manipulation: copy to another variable, print it, mangle it some more, use as argument for another program, etc.

Comment: @MattDMo I am beginning to see how this could be useful. In fact, this is really some powerful stuff. Not just "group capturing" but regex in general. But it will really depend on the tools you use. Is regex supported in cmd in Windows? Are wildcards like `*` and `?` considered to be regex? Maybe not in the common sense? In regex I've seen so far this is known as `.*` and `.`

Comment: I am mainly interested in regex to help me automate common tasks. I've used it a few times lately in Notepad++ for text manipulation. It helps ease boring and repetitive tasks.

Comment: @Sammy the Windows implementation of `*` is slightly different. In any case `.*` means "match any character any number of times". `*` just means "any number of times". `?` means different things in different implementations. The details depend on the regex flavor you are using. Notepad++ has its own which may differ slightly from what you are learning. However, learning any regex flavor greatly simplifies understanding any other. They are all similar.

Answer (score 1):

**Shorter one:**

```
(.*)\.pdf$
```

**Why capturing/grouping:**

When you are either *passing* the regex to a program, or using it in your program, you need to **store** the **matches**, you use grouping.

Taking the example regex above, the program checks if the regex matches, if it does, you can simply get the phrase you **enclosed** it with <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>

Demo:

```
String stringToCheck = "example.pdf";           // Example string for testing
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)\.pdf$");      // Matching regex
Matcher m = r.matcher(stringToCheck);           // Java's own component to 'match' the string, proccessing is here
if (m.matches()) {                              // Check if the regex has matched
                                                // What? How to reterive the filename?
                                                // That's why we grouped our filename in the regex
    String filename = m.group(1);               // Reterive the first grouped part
    System.out.println(filename);               // Java's own way to print string, this is printing filename
}                                               // ??? PROFIT
```